# How can I have a div like this?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I want to have a welcome page like this:

[image: Image showing desired outcome.]

But instead I get this:

[image: Image showing actual result.]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: 0;
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

#container1 {
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#left {
  height: 500px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

#right {
  height: 500px;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main id="container1" class="container my-6">
  <div class="">
    <div id="left" class="col-lg-6 my-3">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <div id="right" class="col-lg-6 my-3">
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

I don't know why my container doesn't fully fit the body of the page, and my left and right don't go in the middle and stretch width to each other's end.

Comment: Try using grid or bootstrap, you will figure it out easily

Comment: The biggest problem with your code (it appears you are using bootstrap), your `left` and `right` divs are not direct children of the `container1` so they aren't flex children. Remove the wrapping `<div>` elements and it will work. Also, there is absolutely no reason to use `float` on the right and left, since that's what flex is for.

Comment: @Aleksandar they are using bootstrap. It's a typo type question since the `col-lg-6` elements are not direct children of the container.

Comment: @disinfor it worked sir! thanks! but the only problem left.. is my container1 doesn't fully fit the whole screen space

Comment: @FoxcyLoxcy I've added an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bunch of errors in your code. I commented out the CSS you don't need:

1. No need for `float`, that's what flex is for.
2. `display: table-cell` is being overwritten by `display: flex`
3. Use [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) to set the properties of your `left` and `right` divs.
4. Remove the containing elements around those.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: 0;
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  /* NOT NEEDED: align-items: center;*/
}

#container1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* NOT NEEDED: display: table-cell; */
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  /* This is probably unneeded. align-items, aligns elements on the cross access - which in this case would be vertically aligned in the center since flex-direction by default, is row */
  align-items: center;
}

#left {
  height: 500px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 20px;
  /* NOT NEEDED float: left; */
  /* NOT NEEDED width: 100%; */
  flex: 1 1 50%;
}

#right {
  height: 500px;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  /* NOT NEEDED float: left; */
  /* NOT NEEDED width: 100%; */
}
```

```html
<main id="container1" class="container my-6">
  <div id="left" class="col-lg-6 my-3">
  </div>
  <div id="right" class="col-lg-6 my-3">
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes mostly from the `div`s without classes, that shouldn't be there. 
But you're also mixing floats, with flex and tables. Just stick with flex like in this example:

```css
html, body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.left {
  background: #215f40;
}

.right {
  background: #092414;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```